# Classic ASP.net not loading in visual studio

Tags: asp.net

We have this old ASP.net website which requires some basic link updates and to place some hard coded images aside from our CMS.
Now i downloaded the entire website from the FTP to load up and test on my local machine.
But when i tried loading it in visual studio it loads perfectly, but when i try to start the website to test if its loading it does not load in my browser.
After that i started googling away looking for solutions, but i did not find any that worked for me.

I attached an image with the problem im facing, i hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsTlW.png)

Comment: Did you follow the stuff in "More Information" from your Screenshot ? Your question is too broad to give you an answer.

Comment: Tried it all, did not fix anything.

Comment: It looks like you may have the wrong .Net Framework version set in the Visual Studio project. Or, you may have two ScriptResourceHandler sections in the web.config file, and only one is allowed.

Comment: How do i got about fixing that?

Comment: I think i fixed the first issue, now i got this:

Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80004005'

Er is een schijf- of netwerkfout opgetreden.

/www/_conn.asp, line 46